# Downloading latest artifacts from artifactory using Bamboo plugin

Tags: artifactory, bamboo

I am new to artifactory, and have managed to get my artifacts uploaded, using the following filespec:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "target": "generic-local/MyAppName/${bamboo.BUILD_MAJOR}.${bamboo.BUILD_MINOR}.${bamboo.BUILD_STREAM}.${bamboo.buildNumber}/",
      "pattern": "Output/Release/*.*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This appears to work, I have a project folder, with a folder for each version below it, and the artifacts within.

How can I write an *unrelated* download task to get the latest build artifacts?  By unrelated, I mean no knowledge of the build counters.

Thanks.

Comment: Should mention, these are windows executable, no java/maven stuff going on here at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're uploading files to Artifactory using [File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs), you have the option of including these files as part of the build-info, which can also be published to Artifactory. If you're using Bamboo, you just need make sure the "Collect build-info" option is selected in *Artifactory Deploy* task, and that the *Publish Build-Info* task is added after ther *Artifactory Deploy* task.

You can then download these artifacts, using the *Artifactory Resolve* task, using the following File Spec:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "generic-local",
      "build": "the-build-name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that this spec includes only the repository where the artifacts are in, and the build name. This will download the artifacts of the latest build run published to Artifactory.
If you'd like to download the artifacts of a specific build rum, just add the buiod number as follows:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "generic-local",
      "build": "the-build-name/the-buil;d-number"
    }
  ]
}
```

This functionality is not specific to Bamboo only. It is supported by all of [JFrog Artifactory's CI integrations](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Build+Integration).
You can read more about File Spec [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs).

Comment: Is this supported by the OSS version?  My build throws this exception when I try and take the latest without specifying a version                                                                             
                                                                                                                                         
             
`[Step 1/4] Error occurred while resolving dependencies from the spec: LATEST is not supported in Artifactory OSS.`

Comment: The API used by JFrog CLI to fetch the latest build number is indeed not available in the OSS addition of Artifactory.

Comment: And the sortby and limit isn't supported on teamcity.  The documentation for jfrog arrifactory is really really bad, spelling mistakes, missing information, out of date information.  The product itself is limited in the OSS version.   I have given up, and just going to use Apache archiva instead. Even a simple task of sharing the latest artifacts between CI systems is frought with problems in arrifactory.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve artifacts from Artifactory, use the [Artifactory Generic Resolve task](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Bamboo+Artifactory+Plug-in#BambooArtifactoryPlug-in-TheArtifactoryGenericResolveTask).

In the file spec, use ["sortBy" and "limit"](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-DownloadSpecSchema) to get the latest artifacts.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. It will obviously get the newest version, if an old build is rerun, I can imagine it will be promoted to the newest, which isn't ideal. Is there a way to add a build number property that ensures rebuild of older codes doesn't result in wrong versions being downloaded?

Comment: Came to the conclusion that Artifactory OSS has been deliberately crippled. None of the suggestions work in the team city plug in, the functionality isn't supported.